# Cookies are not getting stored while using CefSharp RequestContext

Tags: c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I am trying to use the following code where dirCache1 will change to dirCache2 while crawling second request/url. I dont want to call Cef.Shutdown after a link is crawled. I want to crawl next link with new dirCache folder. When I try this, cookies are not getting stored. Please help.

```
var reqContext = RequestContext.Configure()
   .WithCachePath("C:\TEST\dirCache1")
   .WithPreference("enable_do_not_track", "True")
   .WithPreference("webrtc.ip_handling_policy", "disable_non_proxied_udp")
   .WithPreference("webrtc.multiple_routes_enabled", "False")
   .WithPreference("webrtc.nonproxied_udp_enabled", "False")
   .WithPreference("webrtc.udp_port_range", "")
   .Create();
```

Comment: What value did you use for CefSettings.RootCachePath? See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3111#issuecomment-629713608

Comment: Not setting RootCachePath as it will be different from RequestContext CachePath. Do I need to set it?

Comment: Yes you will as detailed in the link I posted.